# Breaking up Wiener processes with indicator functions?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Consider a Wiener process $W_t$ which is adapted to $\mathscr{F}_t$, where this filtration has all of the standard properties. I'm also working with a stock-standard probability space here.

I want to know if the following useful identities are correct:

- $W_t = {1}_{\{W_t \geq 0\}}W_t + {1}_{\{W_t < 0\}}W_t$
- $|W_t| = {1}_{\{W_t \geq 0\}}W_t - {1}_{\{W_t < 0\}}W_t$

Note that I mean "$=$" as *actually* equal and not only equal in distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For every real number $x$,
$$\mathbf 1_{\{x \geqslant 0\}} + \mathbf 1_{\{x < 0\}}=1,\qquad
x\mathbf 1_{\{x \geqslant 0\}}- x\mathbf 1_{\{x < 0\}}= |x|
$$

Comment: So this confirms the two identifies path-wise. (i.e. for $W_t(\omega)$ and $|W_t(\omega)|$). However, I'm not quite sure how this can then be extended to demonstrate the case for the full $W_t$ random variable?

Comment: What you call *the case for the full random variable* is not clear to me. Random variables $X,Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ are such that $X=Y$ (almost surely) if and only if $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ for (almost) every $\omega$ in $\Omega$. The identities in my post show this is the case here.

Comment: Okay, so you're suggesting that I use the fact that the identities I've stated hold path-wise (i.e. $\text{P-a.s.}$ under filtration equipped probability space with measure $P$), and therefore hold in all possible states of the world, and therefore the expressions are correct as they're stated.

Comment: One can forget the filtration context altogether. There are only functions, defined on some set $\Omega$.

Comment: Okay, so can I confirm that this is the correct argument: `(i)`$W_t(\omega) = {1}_{\{W_t(\omega) \geq 0\}}W_t(\omega) + {1}_{\{W_t(\omega) < 0\}}W_t(\omega)$ holds for each $\omega \in \Omega$. `(ii)`Therefore, $W_t = {1}_{\{W_t \geq 0\}}W_t + {1}_{\{W_t < 0\}}W_t$ is true (almost surely).

Comment: Your previous-to-last comment is correct (and one can omit *almost surely* in it).